# mongosh --eval returns the result but not the prompt

Tags: mongodb, eval, mongo-shell

Have a problem with a mongosh query

tried to query a mongo rs the following way:

`mongosh mongodb://xx.yy.zz.kk:27010,xx.yy.zz.ll:27010,kk.yy.zz.ff:27010/somedb --username someuser --password somepassword --authenticationDatabase admin --eval 'db.getCollection("somecollection").findOne();'`

it returns the result but never gives me back my (bash shell) prompt.

update: trying the same query from another host on another subnet, returns the result and returns to shell. so its maybe not mongosh related.

Comment: Did you try the same with classic `mongo` shell? In my opinion the new `mongosh` is not really usable yet.

Comment: yes, I see its not really there. I've not installed mongo as I don't want the whole database server suite on the box I'm querying a remote server from. I just need a "cli" to query mongo , also, legacy mongo shell is [deprecated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo/)

Comment: The result should be printed to your console, Do you get expected result when you run the `findOne` from shell?

Comment: yes. but as I see, the same command works from another machine from another subnet so it could be something either selinux, or sockets related. I don't know to be honest.

Comment: The run directly from shell (without --eval), it should return an error.

Comment: works fine. but I can't exit from the shell with ```quit``` just w/ ctrl+d

Comment: AS said, use the legacy shell. Yes, it's deprecated but unlike the new `mongosh` it is actually working.

Comment: @iriseth what version of `mongosh` are you using? This might be a bug but I can't reproduce it with the most recent version (1.0.5).

Answer (score 0):

When you use `--eval` then command is executed and shell is terminated afterwards. If you like to keep the shell open use option `--shell`

Comment: I actually just need the output. and my (bash) shell prompt. I don't need the mongo shell.